# What determines whether or not the %HOME% environment variable is expanded?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I have two machines (both on an AD domain). On one Windows 10 PC, if I open a command prompt and echo the %HOME% environment variable, I get this result:

```
C:\Users\johndoh>echo %home%
C:\Users\johndoh
```

On the other Windows 10 PC, I get this result:

```
C:\Users\johndoh>echo %home%
%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
```

On both machines, if I echo the %HOMEDRIVE% and %HOMEPATH% environment variables, I get the same result:

```
C:\Users\johndoh>echo %HOMEDRIVE%
C:

C:\Users\johndoh>echo %HOMEPATH%
\Users\johndoh

C:\Users\johndoh>
```

Likewise, both have the same registry entries for %HOME%:
[image: regedit]

How can I get the second machine to expand the environment variables within %HOME%?

Edit:
I restarted the problematic machine, and that fixed the problem. However, I think I recall doing that before and the problem comes back after awhile. Is it possible for some script or program to turn off variable expansion for the entire system until the next reboot?

Comment: What happens if you run `SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`?

Comment: I ran:
`
C:\Users\johndoh>SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
`
`
C:\Users\johndoh>echo %home%
%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
`
Is that what you meant?

Comment: Is the registry entry on the non-working PC also a `reg_expand_sz`? It is this registry key type which will expand variables inside the key. If it is `reg_sz` it will not expand.

Comment: @Appleoddity, it is `reg_expand_sz` on the non-working machine. I restarted the machine and it fixed the problem. I'll edit my question with more details.